# How many tables to use for users uploading photos in application?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm currently learning PostgreSQL and am working on creating an Instagram clone for practice.

Ive finished user registration and am working on users uploading photos. I was wondering if I should have a table for photos that has the userid in one of the columns, or if I should have three tables altogether, one for users, one for photos, and a third that has the userid and pictureid.

Which would be the best approach?

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where stuck.. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research.

Comment: We can't tell anyone what is "best" in engineering unless they define it in enough detail & give enough relevant details that all would agree on a valuation. And it is chaotically dependent on details. Even if that could be done it's too much for a question here. And then you would need to explain why you can't evaluate that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a relation **One to Many** ( `|User| 1 <--> * |Photo|` ), you juste have to create 2 tables. The `Photo` table will have it's owner's ID.
You need 3 tables if, for exemple, a Photo can have multiple owners. Then it's a **Many to Many relation** ( `|User| * <--> * |Photo|` ). In that case you'll have a table that will have `OWNER_ID` and `PICTURE_ID` with the private key being `(OWNER_ID, PICTURE_ID)`

And don't hesitate to think about the future, changing such things is really complicated when you have a real app in prod. So, if you think there is a chance that Photos will later have many owner, use 3 tables

I just want to add that this is not a good practice to store files in an SQL database. For storing files, the best practice is to use file storage, or object storage.